# How to save a SetFit trainer locally after training

Tags: sentence-similarity, huggingface, sentence-transformers

I am working on an HPC with no internet access on worker nodes and the only option to save a SetFit trainer after training, is to push it to HuggingFace hub. How do I go about saving it locally to disk?

https://github.com/huggingface/setfit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

setfit has this class method

```
model._save_pretrained(save_directory)
```

and to load it

```
saved_model = SetFitModel._from_pretrained(save_directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with either pickle or joblib

```
import pickle
import joblib

pickle.dump(trainer, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))
joblib.dump(trainer, 'model.joblib')
```

And load in the future with:

```
job_model = joblib.load('model.joblib')
pkl_model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to pushing your Trainer to the Hub as described in [SetFit for Text Classification](https://github.com/huggingface/setfit/blob/main/notebooks/text-classification.ipynb), you can save your trainer locally and use it for prediction.

There is a predict method in the [source code](https://github.com/huggingface/setfit/blob/main/src/setfit/trainer.py#L418). You can use that same method to make predictions from your SetFit object

Save your model locally:

```
import joblib

# trainer is you SetFit object: setfit.trainer.SetFitTrainer
joblib.dump(trainer, 'my-awesome-setfit-model.joblib')
```

Load your model and make a classification or inference from your model:

```
# Load the trainer
trainer = joblib.load('my-awesome-setfit-model.joblib')

# Use the model and predict
trainer.model.predict(["i loved the spiderman movie!", "pineapple on pizza is the worst "])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sklearn wrapper](https://github.com/huggingface/setfit/blob/ebee18ceaecb4414482e0a6b92c97f3f99309d56/src/setfit/modeling.py#L318):

### Train the model

```
from setfit.modeling import SKLearnWrapper
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = SentenceTransformer("sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2")
clf = SKLearnWrapper(model, LogisticRegression())

sentences = ["good", "bad", "very good"]
labels = [1, 0, 1]
clf.fit(sentences, labels)
pred1 = clf.predict(["gooood"])
```

### Save the model

```
path = "model1"
clf.save(path)
```

### Load the model

```
clf = SKLearnWrapper(None, None)
clf.load(path)
```

### Test

```
pred2 = clf.predict(["gooood"])
assert pred1 == pred2
```